# Building a Play 2.6 project from IntelliJ builds nothing

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I'm running my head into the ground trying to create a new "hello-world" level blank Play 2.6 project. I have successfully opened and run one of their example starter projects from the Play site in IntelliJ, and it works without issue.

However when creating my own I follow all the steps:
New project -> Play 2.x -> Setup as pictured:

[image: Build Page]

And about 10 seconds later, this is all I get:

[image: Build Result]

From my understanding, the whole structure should be available and displaying to me.

I don't know if it matters, but my Scala version is 2.12.1 and my IntelliJ version is the full version 2017.1 . I checked and the Playframework Support plugin is enabled, and so is Scala.

I'm also open to creating a "blank" one in SBT and then importing it into Scala, but unsure of how to do that either.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you managed to get this working or work around it? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: worked around it. It may have something to do with 2.6 being so new (<3 weeks at the time of this post). Although IntelliJ did release an update on Play and Scala just today, haven't tried it. Build the project from SBT in your desired location first, and then import the project from IntelliJ as an SBT project and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Refresh your IDE, the latest Intellij IDEA version (2017.2) with up to date plugins creates a new Play 2.x project without a problem.