# IntelliJ doesn't show project structure correctly

Tags: intellij-idea

I followed instruction from following link to create a Play project in IntelliJ but IntelliJ doesn't show correct structure.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-play-2-x.html

Snapshot attached
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised the issue with IntelliJ support. It seems to be fixed in the latest release of IntelliJ ultimate edition. If you run the default application and see 'no jdk error', go to edit configurations and select the top level project in play module (see pic)[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and found this: [Building a Play 2.6 project from IntelliJ builds nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44933083/building-a-play-2-6-project-from-intellij-builds-nothing)

So now we're 3 people with the same problem. I haven't found any open bug report or issue anywhere.

I got it working using the workaround that OP from the other question suggested: "Build the project from SBT in your desired location first, and then import the project from IntelliJ as an SBT project and you should be good to go."

To do that just run `sbt new playframework/play-scala-seed.g8` (assuming you have SBT installed and PATH configured), and import that.

Comment: My workaround - I downloaded Scala starter example from https://www.playframework.com/download#starters . Then did `sbt run` (which took ages!, asked another question on SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45116619/do-i-need-to-download-play-framework-for-each-project), tested it on `localhost:9000` and then imported it in IntelliJ. The amount of time this is taking is excruciating!

Comment: After the first time, once everything is downloaded to your local repositories, it should start up faster